# XNA stretching and filling 2D and 3D content

Tags: c#, xna

I've written out a detailed description of my problem here:

http://www.codebot.org/articles/?doc=9574

The basic gist of my question is what is the **best way** to get XNA to behave like my OpenGL apps, in that I want content stretched to fill a window based on my designed proportions rather than the actual window size.

Further information, this problem relates to varying window or viewport size. In my previous OpenGL apps I would allow uses to switch between windowed and fullscreen mode, and I'd also allow windows to be resized. The problem I am running into with XNA is handling different fullscreen and windowed sizes. In OpenGL I'd detect a when window was resized and adjust the viewport so that the field of view was always fixed to a resolution aspect ratio. I would also create a 2D projection drawing, using the glOrtho function, to a fixed resolution.

The XNA examples I've worked through using SpriteBatch and SpriteFont, text and sprites seem to render in screen pixels. That is, all 2D output is rendered with square pixels and no stretching. In my XNA apps I'd rather they stretch to fill a window in the proportions I've designed. My question is, how can 2D and 3D stretching and filling, like I've done in OpenGL, best be done in XNA?

Comment: For the sake of SO, could you please edit your question to include more details from your blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **3D** content using `BasicEffect` (and other effects that implement `IEffectMatrices` as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/05/05/effect-interfaces-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)) you can use the appropriate members to set your World, View and Projection matrices as you like.

So where in your OpenGL code you have this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(FieldOfView, Width / Height, 1, 1000);
```

The equivalent in XNA is to set a projection matrix on the effect, like so:

```
effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
        FieldOfView, Width / Height, 1, 1000);
```

---

Now, for **2D**. Here's what you might have in OpenGL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
```

If you're using an effect (even with `SpriteBatch`, as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)), the basic idea is the same as with 3D:

```
effect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
        0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
```

---

Now, if you're using `SpriteBatch` *without* a custom effect (and **I would recommend this**, if you don't actually need a custom effect), you have to bare in mind that, by default, `SpriteBatch` uses an projection equivalent to:

```
effect.Projection = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0)
        * Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0,
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
```

Which gives a "client space" (top left is (0,0)) coordinate system, aligned to pixel centres.

If you want to adjust that space, you may pass in a transformation matrix to `SpriteBatch.Begin` ([this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx)).

So to get the effect you are after (where a fixed number of world units appear on screen, no matter the screen size), you can to counter-act the built-in projection from client-space with this transformation:

```
Matrix.CreateScale(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 640f,
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 480f, 1f);
```

(Assuming you want your visible world space to be 640 by 480.)

---

I recommend having a look through the documentation for [XNA's Matrix on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197914.aspx), to see what kind of matrices you can create.

Comment: Okay thanks. I had to reverse your division though. It should be: Matrix.CreateScale((float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 640f, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 480f, 1f);

Answer (score 0):

For 2D drawing I added this to my LoadContent() method, where effect is private field in my Game class ...

```
effect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice)
{
  TextureEnabled = true,
  VertexColorEnabled = true
};
```

And then added this inside my Draw() method ...

```
effect.Projection = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0) * 
  Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 1);
batch.Begin(0, null, null, null, RasterizerState.CullNone, effect);
```

It seems to work fine. Now 2D images and fonts are scaled correctly when the window is resized. You recommended not using a custom effect. Is creating an instance of BasicEffect what you meant, or did you mean something else? That is I don't see how to create a custom project matrix without using an effect instance.

Comment: The final parameter to `SpriteBatch.Begin`, in its form with all arguments specified ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx)), is a transformation (not a projection) matrix. I would use that, rather than creating a BasicEffect. Just pass `null` for the effect.